# <img src> w/ timeout?

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have some tracking pixels on our site, that I'd like to protect against them impacting our user experience if their servers are down or slow. What's the easiest way to specify a maximum time the browser should attempt to load a given img - i.e. try for 100ms and then give up? (I'd rather not track a given customer than have a server hang on the third-party server impact our site).

Answer (score 3):

You could insert the `<img>` with JavaScript and use `setTimeout()` to remove it after 100ms.

Example with jQuery:

```
var tracker = $("<img>", { src: trackingUrl }).appendTo(document.body);
setTimeout(function() { tracker.remove(); }, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

you should load them when the document is ready.
or at the lastline ( in the html). this way- it wont hurt the user experience.
document ready can be also used with jQuery.

but you can use window.load.

*as a rule(not always) - all scripts should be at the end of the page.*

> if you want to FORCE time out KILL :

create an `img` tag.

attach the `load` event to the img (this function will set flag : downloaded=1;)

set the src.

with `setTimeout` Function your gonna kill the img.

how ?

if after X MS the downloaded ==0 then kill.

so : each load event( from the IMg) is setting a flag ( downloaded=1).

your timeout function dont care about nothing!!!  after x MS she going to kill the img - only if the downloaded==0.

Comment: Yeah, but then the status bar still shows data being downloaded, so it looks unfinished. I'd really like to have an actual way to define a timeout.

Comment: Why bother with the condition rather than remove the `<img>` anyway?

Comment: @Electro what is KILL ? kill is when it didnt finish to download ! but maybe it did finish to download - and i dont want to remove the img  ( downloaded=1).

Comment: But for the sake of simplicity, why should you *not* remove the `<img>`?

Comment: @Electro its a  tracking pixels. the problem is that sometimes the pixel hoster is very slow.... so he wants to prevent waiting.... and kill  - remove the img after 2 sec( for example) if NOT SUCCESS. but if it did success within the 2 SEC ( downloaded==1) so dont remove the img.

Comment: Tracking pixels don't need the image to remain after the request is complete.

Comment: @Electro thats right. but to remove them with no need - because its already there - i see this as a waist. if the OP didnt have a problem with speed- he would have left those pixels there. It doesnt really matters you know... you can remove/leave them.

Comment: The waste is in the extra code to track the state of the `<img>`.

Comment: @Electro what about 2 pixles that 1 is seeking for the other ? and you remove 1 of them...?  you shouldnt remove just because you want. youll never know what scripts are really doing behind.

Comment: We don't know his requirements, and he is creating the tracking pixel dynamically - he has to pass it around or give it special properties anyway if he wants some other code to use it. Simple is better.

Answer (score 0):

as `img.parentNode.removeChild(img)`

Not all `img` have containers.

```
var img = new Image()
img.src = '...third-party server...'
setTimeout(function() {
  img.removeAttribute('src')
}, 100)
```

Comment: Can you add some more explanation such that others can learn from your code?

Comment: The result of my experiment.

Answer (score -1):

You could call a server process in the IMG tag. Let it worry about timing out the load.

Comment: There already is a server process in the tag: it provides the "image". It's that which is taking the time, and that needs to be cancelled in the client. If the cancellation is handed off to the server, the cancellation will take time too.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to use javascript to do this, there's nothing native to HTML/HTTP that would do this on a page basis. Google around for "HTML IMG timeout".

Comment: That's exactly what I Googled to find this page.